# Support for mapping keys in multi-line blocks is deprecated since Symfony 4.3 and will throw a ParseException in 5.0

Tags: symfony, deprecated, multiline, deprecation-warning

I have a problem. After updating to Symfony 4.4 I got the following deprecation warning
`Support for mapping keys in multi-line blocks is deprecated since Symfony 4.3 and will throw a ParseException in 5.0.
2x in AccountControllerTest::testSettings from App\Tests\Controller
1x in AccountControllerTest::testPageUser from App\Tests\Controller`

I have absolutely no clue what this means.

testSettings from App\Tests\Controller:

```
    public function testSettings() {
    $crawler = self::$userClient->request('GET', '/nl/account/settings.html');
    $this->assertSuccesfulResponse(self::$userClient->getResponse());
    $crawler = $this->form(self::$userClient, $crawler, 'submit', array(), '/\/nl\/account/');
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This mean that you potentially have a multi line key in your somewhere in a Yaml file and it's not supported by symfony and in symfony 5.0 it will throw an exception not a warning !

Something like that:

```
 this
 is
 multi
 key:  test
```

Comment: Do you know if there is an easy way to search where this is?

Comment: No idea about that

Comment: Updating to 5.0 gave the error exactly where it was. Thanks!